# How to use NLog in static class where everything else is wired with Autofac

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, autofac, nlog

My MVC app is wired with Autofac. I have also configured NLog which works as expected in my controller classes. My nLogger is registered as below:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LoggerService<>))
  .As(typeof(ILoggerService<>)).SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
```

And the constructor of the ILoggerService is:

```
public LoggerService()
{
    SourceClass = typeof (T).FullName;
    Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(SourceClass);
 }
```

Now I have also got many static helper classes that I use. For example:

```
public static class Helper
{
   public static string GenerateQrBitmap(string secret, string issuer, string userEmail)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

But I want to be able to use the logger in these Helper classes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why `static` classes aren't great.

You have two options:

1. Make them not `static` (and register them with Autofac) and take
   `ILoggerService` as a constructor parameter.
2. Change their methods
   (e.g. `GenerateQrBitmap`) to take a `ILoggerService` as a parameter.

I'd suggest the former.

The alternative is to use the **Service Locator** pattern - and have `Helper` resolve directly against the container. I will not show you how to do this, since I don't recommend it. It makes the code harder to unit test, and it hides your dependencies. But if you Google `Autofac Service Locator static class c#` I'm sure you'll work it out.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Demodave Example of what exactly (1? 2? something else?)? What is your level of experience with Autofac?